# Writing to SD card from Windows CE fails?

Tags: xml, windows-mobile-6.5

I am writing XML files to a SD-card from Windows-CE using `Dataset.WriteXML()`. Most of the times it go through correctly, but some times I'm getting an error:

```
    Error Time:7/25/12 1:17:07 PM Message:  Details:
System.IO.IOException: IOException
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String str)
   at System.IO.FileStream.WriteCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Write(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush(Boolean flushStream, Boolean flushEncoder)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Write(Char value)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextWriter.InternalWriteEndElement(Boolean longFormat)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextWriter.WriteEndElement()
   at System.Data.DataTextWriter.WriteEndElement()
   at System.Data.XmlDataTreeWriter.XmlDataRowWriter(DataRow row, String    encodedTableName)
   at System.Data.XmlDataTreeWriter.Save(XmlWriter xw, Boolean writeSchema)
   at System.Data.DataSet.WriteXml(String fileName, XmlWriteMode mode)
```

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on the exception handler, you should be able to parse the exception and get an HRESULT value. What is that value?